# How to run C2DM sample program in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

Hi I am very new to android. I would like to develop an application in android with C2DM. I have a sample code for C2DM from the following site http://www.ipragmatech.com/power-mobile-app-android-push-notification-c2dm.html . I did the following steps device-> settings-> account & sync -> google account-> add account-> sign in-> gave my account name and password. And then I ran my code ,but its shows some thing

```
  09-30 15:28:22.868: WARN/C2DMReceiver-onRegistered(491): Sending request to Server
  09-30 15:36:52.888: ERROR/C2DMReceiver-onRegistered(614): Connect to /192.168.1.4:8080 timed out
  09-30 15:36:52.888: WARN/C2DMReceiver-onRegistered(614): APA91bGI7fsthXytTrOMWxcldx5haV21e4b98XqLV2C4cnCrq0betXuUa2vrklD0w_Qn6LuzNFDQqqkegfKe1-UL5W8Gce9IXrHjEmBajeAN2lcW7LnTyY0
  09-30 15:37:20.008: DEBUG/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

09-30 15:42:20.059: DEBUG/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

And then it doesn't works. Anybody tell me the procedure for get the registration ID from c2dm server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [doc](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html) and [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html).

Comment: try this: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html